# Customize selection behavior for QTreeView

Tags: qt, qabstractitemmodel, qabstractitemview, qitemselectionmodel

I have `QTreeView` and I want multi selection behavior in case if node is leaf, otherwise single selection behavior, so do not allow to select non-leaf node if some node already selected, and do not allow to select any other node if non-leaf node is selected. 
How to implement that?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to control selection behavior by deriving from `QTreeView` and overloading `selectionCommand`.

Using this method you can check what item was clicked (node/leaf) and then return proper `SelectionFlags`.